# Leetcode Q9 Palindrome Number same code works in Java but not in C++

Tags: c++, palindrome

I tried solving this problem: https://leetcode.com/problems/palindrome-number/
using code:

```
class Solution {
public:
    bool isPalindrome(int x) {
        int rev = 0;
        int temp = x;
        while(temp != 0 && temp > 0){
            rev = rev* 10;
            rev = rev + temp%10;
            temp = temp/10;
        }
        if (rev == x){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
};
```

and got this error in C++:

```
Line 7: Char 22: runtime error: signed integer overflow: 998765432 * 10 cannot be represented in type 'int' (solution.cpp)
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior prog_joined.cpp:16:22
```

The logically same code runs perfectly in Java though. Both java and c++ have int data type ranging from - 2^31 to 2^31-1
(Source:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_data_types.htm,
[https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html#:~:text=int%3A%20By%20default%2C%20the%20int,value%20of%20232%2D1.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html#:%7E:text=int%3A%20By%20default%2C%20the%20int,value%20of%20232%2D1.))
So Why is this error showing up and how can I fix it?
Thanks

Comment: An int is 32bits in java, in C++ it's platform defined (might be only 16 bits).  Try making the int rev into `long rev`

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because 9,987,654,320 is too big to fit in a 32-bit integer.

Solution: Use `long long` instead. That is:

```cpp
long long rev = 0;
long long temp = x;
```

Also, I suggest clearly specify the type of parameter `x`.